# Eclipse Project from a SVN Branch

Tags: eclipse, svn, project

I have to make a bug fix in a existing project.  So I have gone in to my Subversion Repository.  I have created a branch from the existing project's trunk.

Now I need to some how get the newly created Branch into eclipse as a project, so I can edit and test it.

Export The Branch to a local path -> Import as existing project in to Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the eclipse plugins
**Eclipse Subversive**
http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

or 
**Subclipse**
http://subclipse.tigris.org/ 
as the first option and check in/check out the branch,
 or as the second option you can use **tortoisesvn** http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html **subversion**http://subversion.tigris.org/ cliens for check in/check out your eclipse project

Answer (score 0):

Install the svn eclipse plugin

http://subclipse.tigris.org/

and Checkout the branch.